# Split or Merge WCF service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have 5 applications, Four of them have one common web service, and another web service for fifth application. My question is should I club all of them in a single service, or should I segregate them in different services?

Also if I decide to separate each of them, should I make single project with multiple Interfaces and SVCs or different projects for each of them?

Comment: I would keep the service implementations in separate projects, but exposing them through a single service (endpoint such as an IIS website) is ok

Comment: My thoughts were same, however I can not point to benefits of doing so. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Well there are scenarios where you might want to separate the services, say one is region specific and you want to host it closer to the users. so having them in separate projects is good. But you may only have one box on which you want to expose all the services, in this case the since 'sevice end poitn' project makes that easy to deploy and manage

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at two key factors.  The first being deployment.  If you able to bring the whole application down without causing massive panic from your users sure put it all in one project.  If you are in a situation where you will cause mild strokes then separate it.

The second I would look at would be performance.  If you have excessive amounts of concurrent users accessing your service you may also think about separating them.  Or just load balancing the one massive service.

Performance break down

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fkaduk/archive/2014/01/07/rest-wcf-vs-webapi-throughput.aspx

Comment: I have huge servers with load balancer to manage load. One thing I am worried about merging them is WSDL growing too large. I have read that larger WSDL give trouble. Does having a big service on good infrastructure performs worse than having multiple smaller services on same infrastructure? Also think about concurrency and throttling

Comment: If you split it out maybe that could be a reason to upgrade to a WebAPI and go that route.  Section by section.  No more WSDL maintenance worries.